# yii2-multiple-input - Add and remove row in the middle

Tags: yii, yii2, yii-extensions

I am working on a project and using yii2-multiple-input, but I would like to be able to add the row in the middle.

Do you know if this is something that we can do using yii2-multiple-input or do I have to try another approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to sort rows in multiple input:

```
$form->field($model, 'attribute')->widget(MultipleInput::className(), [
    'sortable' => true
]);
```

After adding a new row in the last position, you can move it wherever you want.

For more information, check [here](https://unclead.github.io/yii2-multiple-input/configuration/).